# Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, imagemagick, paperclip

I am using Paperclip and **getting this error on the deployed site, not on my local server**. And that's why it is becoming more difficult for me to get out of this.

```
A Paperclip::Errors::CommandNotFoundError occurred in images#update:
enter code hereCould not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.
```

I have tried these solutions but was not able to fix this (For ubuntu):

1. Ran `apt-get install imagemagick`
2. I don't use brew. So, won't be able to use `brew install imagemagick`
3. Added and deployed these lines to paperclip_options.yml

> :image_magick_path: '/opt/ImageMagick/bin'
> :command_path: '/opt/ImageMagick/bin'

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this error?

Comment: did you try adding this paperclip options in environment file (`config/environments/development.rb`)? Like this `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/ImageMagick/bin/"` ?

Comment: If you ssh into the server and run `convert -version` what do you see?

Comment: I am getting "Command 'convert' not found" message.